# Converting an epoch timestamp to date in vega

Tags: vega

I need to do some light date addition in vega. I'm using the following expression, where `datum.date` is of type Date and `datum.days` is a number:

```
                    'transform': [
                      {
                        'type': 'formula',
                        'expr':
                            'time(datum.date) + (1000*60*60*24*datum.days)',
                        'as': 'x'
                      },
                    ]
```

This works great but it results in a timestamp (eg: `1627057587`) instead of a js Date object. I looked into `toDate()` but that seems to also return a timestamp rather than a Date object.

How do I convert the result of this operation back to a date object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy solution here. Similar to what you have done, you just want to use a formula like so - I'm assuming "x" is your epoch value.

```
{
  type: formula
  expr: datetime(datum.x)
  as: TimestampFromEpoch
}
```

Arguably, this not overly clear in the Vega documentation that this is possible. But does the job :)